# How to prioritise resources based on different factors?

Tags: algorithm, performance, operating-system

I have N resources and each has `cost C`, `current utilisation U` and `efficiency E` associated with it. I want to allocate priority to these resources based on `C`, `U` and `E`.

Given that `U` and `E` are dynamic and will keep changing frequently, what is the best way I can calculate priority?

Comment: Reevaluate frequently?

Comment: Yeah I will of course reevaluate the priority everytime `U` and `E` change. But what should priority function look  like?

Comment: If such parameters as "cost of switching", "change probability" and "time it takes to switch" are not a part of your model, then it does not matter how frequently the efficiency changes, and the formula will be the same as if efficiency never changed and you had to calculate once for a static layout.

Comment: Okay. Can you help me with the formula I should use for the static layout?